# appearing flashing Jquery UI div in other web pages

Tags: css, jquery-ui, jsp

I have added some help sections(eg.UserHelp) in div tag that can be accessed from Menu (link). but ***whenever I clicked other pages via other sub menu (link), those texts written under div (eg.UserHelp) flashed up for 1 or 2 seconds.***

PS: For CSS and JQuery , I didn't change anything.

How can I fix it?

1) This is menu link

```
<li><a href="#" id="dialog_link_user">User Help</a></li>
```

2) This is dialog div

```
<div id="dialog_user" title="USER HELP">
...
</div>
```

3) jquery of dialog

```
<link href="<s:url value="/css/smoothness/jquery-ui-1.8.16.custom.css"/>" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<SCRIPT type="text/javascript" src="<s:url value="/js/jquery-1.6.2.min.js"/>"></SCRIPT>
<SCRIPT type="text/javascript" src="<s:url value="/js/jquery-ui-1.8.16.custom.min.js"/>"></SCRIPT>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){

    // Dialog           
    $('#dialog_user').dialog({
        autoOpen: false,
        width: 600,
        height:300,
        resizable: true,
        position: 'center',
        closeOnEscape: true,
        maxHeight: 300,
        minHeight: 300,
        maxWidth: 600,
        minWidth: 200
    });


    $('#dialog_link_user').click(function(){
        //close other dialog
        $('#dialog_school').dialog('close');
        ....

        $('#dialog_user').dialog('open');
        return false;
    });
});

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

First, change the ID of either the `div` or the `a`. An ID MUST be unique in an HTML document!

```
...  
$('#dialog_user').click(function(event){
    //close other dialog
    $('#dialog_school').dialog('close');
    ....

    $('#dialog_user').dialog('open');
    event.preventDefault();
    return false;
});
...
```

Try that - preventing the default event (i.e. following the link)

Comment: still appear sometimes. So, I tried that. style="display:none;" for div tag. But instead of displaying flashing up texts in div tag, it becomes blank for 1 or 2 seconds because of display:none.

Comment: Oh. I see the issue. Wasn't paying attention before. You've got a `div` and an `a` with the same ID. You can't do that.

Comment: Oh. sorry. my bad. I used different name. I just missed out when I copied and changed the name to post :)